# ajax load function not displaying my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I own a website, and there are some text information.

I tried to display my webpage inside my HTML5 application with the following but I am not getting it

```
<div id=from_server></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(

function ( ) 
{
    $('#from_server').load('http://magician.sdf-eu.org/barebone.html');
});

</script>
```

I need to use ajax because I need to access the php inside my website.

Comment: You are only alerting something, not actually updating a page. Secondly I don't understand why you need to use AJAX because you need to access PHP, can you not just access it when the page is rendering?

Comment: Where's the part that loads something somewhere? I can see just an alert there.

Comment: Please clarify: _but I am not getting it_. Are you getting errors in the browser console?

Comment: I am not getting errors.   It simply is not displaying the page.

I am building a hybrid mobile application.

Comment: You probably are not allowed to load from that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSRF verification may block cross-domain requests.

You may try to explicitly include a CSRF token in your request. I don't know if jQuery's `load` automatically does it, but you can certainly do it with `$.ajax`.

Also, make sure your server sets the `CSRF cookie`. In some cases, it does so automatically, e.g. when there is a `form` in the HTML. Many times, however, you need to explicitly ask it to do so.

Try this script:

```
$(document).ready(function (){

    var request = $.ajax({
        url: 'http://magician.sdf-eu.org/barebone.html',
        beforeSend: secureAjaxForCsrf,
        type: 'GET'
    });

    request.done(function(response){
        $('#from_server').html(response);
    });

    function secureAjaxForCsrf(xhr, settings){
        var csrftoken = getCookie("csrftoken");
        if(!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)){
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        };
    }

    function csrfSafeMethod(method){
        // Returns true if the given method is free of CSRF risk.
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    function getCookie(name){
        var cookieValue = null;
        if(document.cookie && document.cookie != ""){
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
            for(var i=0; i<cookies.length; i++){
                var cookie = $.trim(cookies[i]);
                if(cookie.substring(0, name.length+1) == (name+"=")){
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length+1));
                    break;
                };
            };
        };
        return cookieValue;
    }
});
```